# set asymptote for negative exponential function

Tags: r, distribution

I have a function that produces a negative exponential curve.

Currently, as `d` increases y asymptotes towards 0.

I would like to adjust the equation so that `y` asymptotes at some other value e.g. 0.1., the only other rule I need to keep to is that `y` cannot be greater than 1.

`d` will always be => 0

```
fun_expo <- function(d, z) {
  exp(-d/z)
}

d <- seq(0, 40, by = 0.1)
y <- fun_expo(d, z = 5)

plot(d, y,
     type = "l",
     xlab = "d",
     ylab = "y")
```

[image]

I started off by just adding a constant of 0.1 to my equation e.g.

```
fun_expo <- function(d, z) {
      exp(-d/z) + 0.1
    }
```

But this results in `y` > 1 if `d` is lo, which I don't want to be possible.

I am hoping for an equation that would produce something like the following (the red line is what I want).

[image]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I'll leave an answer here in case it is helpful for others.

I just needed to add a multiplication scalar to the equation, now it works as intended. In the below example, `z` controls the "shape" of the line and `b0` is the lower limit, where the line will asymptote.

```
fun_expo <- function(d, z, b0) {
  (1-b0) * exp(-d * z) + b0
}

d <- seq(0, 20, by = 1)
y <- fun_expo (d, z = 0.8, b0 = 0.1)

plot(d, y,
     type = "l",
     xlab = "d",
     ylab = "y")
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to adjust the range on the vertical axis:

```
d <- seq(0, 40, by = 0.1)
y <- fun_expo(d, z = 5)
plot(x, y, type="l", lwd=2)
lines(x, (y + .1)/1.1, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: I should have been more clear, I'm not interested in the figure, so much as the equation used to generate the curve. The graph was just for illustration purposes. Thanks for taking the time to answer though.